# How I can delete row from MySQL table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem preventing me from proceeding on my project.  I fail to understand what is wrong until a certain row id cannot be deleted when the query is run.

My code, step by step:

(1) This is the button code, which once I click it emits a popup message to confirm delete, and once I confirm delete (OK), on browser it shows as if the row deleted (disappear) and when I refresh the page, data appears again which means it is not deleted.

```
<input type="button" onclick='return deletethis(this)' class="btn btn-
triangle btn-red" value="X">
```

(2) And the java code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deletethis(el){
    var e = $(el).parent().attr('id');
    var cnf = confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?');
    if(cnf == true){
        $(el).parent().parent().hide(1000);
        $.post('deleteAdd.php', {id:e}, function(data){

        });
       }
     }
   </script>
```

(3) This is "deleteAdd.php" file which holds PHP code for deleting

```
<?php
  global $database;
  $uid = $_POST['id'];

  $q = "DELETE FROM sale_daily WHERE id=$uid";
  $r = $database->query($q);
  $rw = $database->fetch_array($r);
  ?>
```

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). enjoy having your database pwn3ed. As well, you don't have "java codes". You have **JAVASCRIPT** code. They're two totally different languages. Have you done any basic debugging, like checking of `e` really contains the value you want in JS, and that it's showing up in `$uid` on the server?

Comment: I don't think you need to fetch anything if you are just deleting a row from the database.

Comment: try to concatenate the post var `"DELETE FROM sale_daily WHERE id=".$uid."`

Comment: also check if you have connection to the database. Try fetching some records as a test to confirm this.

Comment: where is this suppose to get its value from? `$_POST['id']`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong `id` value.

change this line of code:

`var e = $(el).parent().attr('id');`

to

`var e = $(el).parent().attr('value');`